# Insert JSON values in MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've this JSON string:

```
$json = '{
    "bigprodlist": {
        "prods": [
            {
                "code": 55,
                "name": "Comix Book",
                "link": "weblink"
            },
            {
                "code": 85,
                "name": "IT Book",
                "link": "weblink"
            },
            {
                "code": 95,
                "name": "Manga Book",
                "link": "weblink"
            }

        }
    }';
```

I'd like to print every single entry on a webpage using php and then save these entries on a mysql db. 
In the db there is already a "code", "name" and "link" field..

This is what I've tried without luck (to print the stuff on a page):

```
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
echo ($obj["bigprodlist"]["prods"][0]["name"]);
```

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: You have an unmatched "[" in your json string.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5f1d43007139eb9c05cc9da7eb236a8a2989d5b5

Comment: Would you like to expand your question? You mentioned MySQL.

Comment: Damn, I was so close.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, fix your JSON missing end bracket that makes JSON decoding fail (add the `]` after the prods data ), then expand your echo statement with some foreach loops to get the data printed. This is only a simple example to get you on the right track:

```
foreach ($obj["bigprodlist"]["prods"] as $p):
    echo "<div>";
    foreach ($p as $name=>$value):
        echo "<span>".$name.": ".$value."</span>";
    endforeach;
   echo "</div>";
endforeach;
```

You can then use the same loop procedure to get the data into your DB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use json_last_error(); https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Debugging:

```
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
var_dump($obj, json_last_error());
```

You are missing a ] :

```
$json = '{
    "bigprodlist": {
        "prods": [
            {
                "code": 55,
                "name": "Comix Book",
                "link": "weblink"
            },
            {
                "code": 85,
                "name": "IT Book",
                "link": "weblink"
            },
            {
                "code": 95,
                "name": "Manga Book",
                "link": "weblink"
            }
        ] //missing!
    }
}';
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get json output?
It's invalid:

```
Parse error on line 18:
...          }        }    }
----------------------^
Expecting ',', ']'
```

Check your json at http://jsonlint.com/